# how to give a title to each column created with grid.arrange() in R?

Tags: r, gridextra

Does anyone know if it is possible to give a title at each column of graphs created with grid.arrange()?
I know that is possible to give an overall title and a title to each graph but I would need only a column title.
Thank you very much!

```
grid.arrange(c1b, c2a, c3d, c2b, c3a, c2d, c3b, c1a, c1d, ncol=3, nrow=3)
```

Comment: you could use nested arrangeGrob calls for each column and set the top argument in each

Comment: how would you modify this code?

Comment: `grid.arrange(
arrangeGrob(p1, p2, top="A"),
arrangeGrob(p3, p4, top="B"), ncol=2)` - change t suit your Q

Answer (score 2):

Credit to [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

#create a bunch of line graphs with the mtcars dataset
graph1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_line()
graph2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_line()
graph3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) + geom_line()
graph4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_line()

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(graph1, graph2, top = "Column A"),
             arrangeGrob(graph3, graph4, top = "Column B"), ncol = 2)
```

[image: four line graphs, laid out in a grid, with columns]