# Giving a title to each row of graphs created with grid.arrange() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, row, title

I've created 8 graphs using `ggplot` and would like to arrange them into 2 * 4 layout with `grid.arrange()`. Since the 8 graphs actually belong to 2 unique periods (4 graphs each), so it makes more sense to separate them into 2 rows and put a title with "year" label on each row. The output should look something like this:

```html
grid.arrange(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8, nrow = 2)

     year1
g1  g2  g3  g4
     year2
g5  g6  g7  g8
```

I've referenced [this](http://grid.arrange(c1b,%20c2a,%20c3d,%20c2b,%20c3a,%20c2d,%20c3b,%20c1a,%20c1d,%20ncol=3,%20nrow=3)) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677777/how-to-give-a-title-to-each-column-created-with-grid-arrange-in-r) post which suggest that the `arrangeGrob()` function is the key, but when I found this function got my output clung together (it made 4 to cluster into one cell). Could anyone shed some lights on this?